# Projetos antigos com erro após atualização do Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Foi feito uma atualização do Flutter utilizando o comando: git clone -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Após esta atualização, alguns projetos antigos estão com vários erros (segue algumas delas):

```
List _toDoList = [];
```

> Missing type argument for list literal. Try adding an explicit type
>   like 'dynamic', or enable implicit-dynamic in your analysis options
>   file.

```
  setState(() {
    _toDoList = json.decode(data);
  });
```

> A value of type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to a variable of type
>   'List'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the
>   right-hand type to 'List'.

```
Map<String, dynamic> newToDo = Map();
```

> Missing type arguments for generic type 'Map'. Try
>   adding an explicit type like 'dynamic', or enable implicit-dynamic in
>   your analysis options file.

```
title: Text(_toDoList[index]["title"]),
value: _toDoList[index]["ok"],
```

> The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type
>   'String'.

---

Cheguei a executar os seguintes comandos:

```
Flutter clean / Flutter pub cache repair / Flutter pub pub cache repair
```

Mas os erros permanecem

> flutter doctor -v [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on
>   Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.18363.815], locale pt-BR)
>       • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at D:\Desenv\flutter
>       • Framework revision f139b11009 (4 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
>       • Engine revision af51afceb8
>       • Dart version 2.7.2
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 29.0.3)
>       • Android SDK at D:\Desenv\SDK
>       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
>       • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
>       • ANDROID_HOME = D:\Desenv\SDK
>       • Java binary at: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
>       • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
>       • Android Studio at D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
>       • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
>       • Dart plugin version 192.7761
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
>
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
>       • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
>
> • No issues found!

Answer (score 0):

Para ajudar as pessoas que, assim como eu, estão iniciando no desenvolvimento e em Flutter.
Para correção dos erros informados, executei o seguinte procedimento.

1. Desinstalei o VSCode e o Android Studio.
2. Exclui as seguintes pastas (ao desinstalar elas permanecem): 
   C:\Users\usuário.android
   C:\Users\usuário.AndroidStudio3.6
   C:\Users\usuário.vscode
   C:\Users\usuário\AppData\Roaming.dart
   C:\Users\usuário\AppData\Roaming\Code
   C:\Users\usuário\AppData\Roaming\Code
   C:\Users\usuário\AppData\Roaming\Code
3. Exclui a pasta de instalação do Flutter
4. Baixei a versão v1.12.13+hotfix.8 do Flutter
5. Baixei novamente a versão atualizada do VSCode e do Android Strudio
6. Instalei o Flutter seguindo a documentação oficial, inclusive a opção Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)
7. Após todas as configurações, criei um projeto novo com o mesmo nome do projeto antigo
8. Copiei somente os arquivos da pasta LIB e os da pasta assets
9. Executei os comandos: flutter pub get e flutter clean.

Não houve mais informativos de nenhum erro nos projetos, fiz isso com todos os projetos que que eu tinha sem problemas.